# py2neo rel() list indices must be integer not float

Tags: python, neo4j, batch-processing, py2neo

I'm trying to import nodes into Neo4j in a batch. But when I try to execute it, it throws an error: `List indices must be integers, not float`. I don't really understand which listitems, I do have floats, but these are cast to strings...

Partial code:

```
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://127.0.0.1:7474/db/data/")
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)

for ngram, one_grams in data.items():
    ngram_rank = int(one_grams['_rank'])
    ngram_prob = '%.16f' % float(one_grams['_prob'])
    ngram_id = 'a'+str(n)
    ngram_node = batch.create(node({"word": ngram, "rank": str(ngram_rank), "prob": str(ngram_prob)}))

    for one_gram, two_grams in one_grams.items():
        one_rank = int(two_grams['_rank'])
        one_prob = '%.16f' % float(two_grams['_prob'])
        one_node = batch.create(node({"word": one_gram, "rank": str(one_rank), "prob": one_prob}))
        batch.create(rel((ngram_node, "FOLLOWED_BY", one_node))) #line 81 throwing error
        results = batch.submit()
```

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Ngram_neo4j.py", line 81, in probability_items 
    batch.create(rel((ngram_node, "FOLLOWED_BY", one_node))),
File "virtenv\\lib\\site-packages\\py2neo\\neo4j.py", line 2692, in create
    uri = self._uri_for(entity.start_node, "relationships"),
File "virtenv\\lib\\site-packages\\py2neo\\neo4j.py", line 2537, in _uri_for
    uri = "{{{0}}}".format(self.find(resource)),
File "virtenv\\lib\\site-packages\\py2neo\\neo4j.py", line 2525, in find
    for i, req in pendulate(self._requests):,
File "virtenv\\lib\\site-packages\\py2neo\\util.py", line 161, in pendulate
    yield index, collection[index],
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

running neo4j 2.0, py2neo 1.6.1, Windows 7/64bit, python 3.3/64bit

**--EDIT--**

Did some testing, but the error is located in the referencing to nodes.
oversimplified sample code:

```
for key, dict in data.items():                         #string, dictionary
    batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
    three_gram_node = batch.create(node({"word": key}))
    pprint(three_gram_node)
    batch.add_labels(three_gram_node, "3gram")         # must be int, not float

    for k,v in dict.items():                           #string, string
        four_gram_node = batch.create(node({"word": k}))
        batch.create_path(three_gram_node, "FOLLOWED_BY", four_gram_node)
                                            # cannot cast node from BatchRequest obj
    batch.submit()
```

When a node is created `batch.create(node({props}))`, the `pprint` returns a `P2Neo.neo4j. batchrequest object`.
At the line `add_labels()`, it gives the same error as when trying to create a relation: `List indices must be integers, not float`. 
At the `batch.create_path()` line it throws an error saying it can't cast a node from a `P2Neo.neo4j. batchrequest object`.

I'm trying the dirty-debug now to understand the indices.

**--Dirty Debug Edit--**

I've been meddling around with the `pendulate(collection)`  function.
Although I don't really understand how it fits in, and how it's used, the following is happening:
Whenever it hits an uneven number, it gets cast to a float (which is weird, since `count - ((i + 1) / 2)`, where `i` is an uneven number.) This float then throws the `list indices` error. Some prints:

```
count:  3
i= 0
index: 0
(int)index: 0
i= 1             # i = uneven
index: 2.0       # a float appears
(int)index: 2    # this is a safe cast
```

This results in the `list indices` error. This also happens when `i=0`. As this is a common case, I made an additional `if()` to circumvent the code (possible speedup?) Although I've not unit tested this, it seems that we can safely cast index to an int...

The pendulate function as used:

```
def pendulate(collection):
    count = len(collection)
    print("count: ", count)
    for i in range(count):
        print("i=", i)
        if i == 0:
            index = 0
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            index = i / 2
        else:
            index = count - ((i + 1) / 2)
        print("index:", index)
        index = int(index)
        print("(int)index:", index)
        yield index, collection[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

soft debug : print ngram_node and one_node to see what they contains

dirty debug : modify File "virtenv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\util.py", line 161, add a line before :

```
print index
```

You are accessing a collection (a Python list given the traceback), so, for sure, index must be an integer :)

printing it will probably help you to understand why exception raised

(Don't forget to remove your dirty debug afterwards ;))

Answer (score 1):

While it is currently possible for `WriteBatch` objects to be executed multiple times with edits in between, it is inadvisable to use them in this way and this will be restricted in the next version of py2neo. This is because objects created during one execution will not be available during a subsequent execution and it is not easy to detect when this is being requested.

Without looking back at the underlying code, I'm unsure why you are seeing this exact error but I would suggest refactoring your code so that each `WriteBatch` creation is paired with one and only one execution call (`submit`). You can probably achieve this by putting your batch creation within your outer loop and moving your submit call out of the inner loop into the outer loop as well.

Comment: I tried this, but it's in the rel() function. The refferencing to nodes, as explained in your cookbook doesn't seem to function. Made an edit with details